# Sorting from smallest to largest

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a field capacity in mytable .

I want to sort the fetch data by capacity from smallest to largest

these values are

```
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 18"
6" x 12"
10" x 20"
12" x 24"
```

I want this results

```
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 18"
10" x 20"
12" x 24"
```

if I using this query

```
select * from mytable order by capacity ASC
```

than the result is

```
10" x 20"
12" x 24"
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 18"
```

if I using this query

```
select * from mytable order by capacity + 0 ASC
```

than the result is

```
6" x 12"
6" x 12"
6" x 18"
6" x 12"
10" x 20"
12" x 24"
```

Comment: Are they stored like that as a string?  What are the column names and stuff so I can write up a script for you if you'd like?

Comment: Is it possible to edit the table? If possible, you will probably find it much nicer to use two numeric columns to store this data, rather than one character string.

Comment: capacity field as varchar(255)

Comment: @PradeepSingh why not changing the schema of your table? see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very bad schema for a table. The best way is to create a table that separates them (*the values*) into two columns: *width* and *height*. Example,

```
CREATE TABLE Dimension
(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Width` INT,
   `Height` INT,
   CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

then you can now insert your records like this,

```
INSERT INTO Dimension (`Width`, `Height`) VALUES (6, 12), (6,18), (10, 12);
```

and simply use this query to order the result

```
SELECT *
FROM Dimension
ORDER BY (`width` * `height`) DESC
```

---

But to answer your question without changing the schema, create a `USER DEFINE FUNCTION` in you server,

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR
(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

then use this query,

```
SELECT CAST(SPLIT_STR(REPLACE(`capacity`, '"', '') ,'x', 1) as SIGNED) width,
       CAST(SPLIT_STR(REPLACE(`capacity`, '"', '') ,'x', 2) as SIGNED) height
FROM tableName
ORDER BY  (width * height) DESC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad0fe/6)

Comment: This really is the best answer. Only use one of the other answers if it is absolutely not possible to change the schema for the table.

Comment: @jmilloy I disagree.  This is the best _solution_ but not the best _answer_.  It's different.  Often times the OPs don't have access, time, etc to make the kinds of changes like what John Woo suggested.

Comment: @John Woo Why do you create a function SPLIT_STR instead of using SUBSTRING_INDEX?

Comment: I have a huge data in database and the values are not the same syntax

Comment: vaslues are 1/4" x 4', 1 3/4" x 4", 1 Ton x 03"

Comment: @PradeepSingh You're options are to 1) change the schema so that the syntax is consistent, 2) compute the capacity in sql using string functions, or 3) compute the capacity in php after fetching the data. In all three options, you will need to determine a method for converting the string values to capacities, and right now we can't help with that part. If you need help with that part, you will need to completely specify the problem, in particular examples of possible values and how they should sort (e.g. how does a ton relate to an inch?)

Comment: @PradeepSingh In particular, **there is no built-in mysql function for computing capacity from a varchar**. You have to compute it yourself, either before the query, during the query, or after the query.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this...

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(capacity, 'x', 1) AS width, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(capacity, 'x', -1) AS height 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY width+0 ASC, height+0 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to loop through the results and multiply each value together.  Using a custom sort afterwards you could then have the result you're looking for.

```
$sortedArray = array();
$array       = array(
    '6" x 12"', '6" x 18"', '6" x 12"', '6" x 12"', '10" x 12"'
);

// loop through rowset
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $parts = explode(' x ', str_replace('"', '', $row));
    $sortedArray[][($parts[0] * $parts[1])] = $row;
}

// custom sort - PHP 5.3 required for anonymous functions
usort($sortedArray, function($a, $b) {
    return (array_keys($a) > array_keys($b));
});
```

Alternatively, if you do not have PHP 5.3, then you could simply change the usort like this:

```
function mySort($a, $b)
{
    return (array_keys($a) > array_keys($b));
}

usort($sortedArray, 'mySort');
```

Answer (score 1):

change this query

```
select * from mytable order by capacity ASC
```

to

```
select * from mytable order by trim(capacity) ASC
```

It also helped me two days ago...

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot refactor the database to store the size in two numeric columns, but you want to achieve the sort in mysql rather that php post-processing, you can try to extract the dimensions and cast the values to numbers, something like

```
SELECT dimensions
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dimensions, '"', 1) AS SIGNED) * 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEFT(dimensions, LENGTH(dimensions)-1), ' ', -1) AS SIGNED)
    ASC
```

Or, better, similar to Ashwini's answer:

```
SELECT dimensions
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(dimensions, 'x', 1) + 0) * 
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(dimensions, 'x', -1) + 0)
    ASC
```

You'll probably need to tweak the two substring index parts.

Another way to extract the values you need:

- extract the first dimension (the substring from the beginning to the first ": `LEFT(dimensions, INSTR(dimensions, '"'))`
- extract the second dimension (the substring from after the x to 1 less than the end): RIGHT(LEFT(dimensions, LENGTH(dimensions-1)), INSTR(dimensions, 'x') + 1)

Answer (score 1):

Do a favor for your self if you can. Create 2 separete columns for this data and, if you don't want to concatenate the values in PHP, contactenate with SQL:

```
select contact(width, '" x ', height, '"') as capacity from mytable order by width asc, height asc
```

Also, ordering by width and height separatelly is much more eficient and produces the desired result.